# How to find hcaptcha callback function

Tags: javascript, python, captcha, hcaptcha

so I need help in finding the hcaptcha callback function on a website. There is no submit button on the website so I assume they use the hcaptcha callback function. The website is https://discord.com/register
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: https://docs.hcaptcha.com/?

Comment: Exact solution is right here https://medium.com/@aleksandlario/how-to-automate-midjourney-image-generation-with-puppeteer-6aea1b366c75

Answer (score 2):

this code should help you:

```
https://gist.github.com/kratzky/1fa9eb951037eb065459ecfff7d94236
```

Tutorial:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k18somx4dkuyicl/hcaptcha.callback.mp4?dl=0
```