# Node JS submit hCaptcha token by callback

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, captcha, hcaptcha

I'm trying to figure out how should I submit a hcaptcha token on a site which doesn't have a submit button. I'm using a 3rd party service called 2captcha to get a solution for a hcap challange. I manage to insert it into the textarea it should be in and `data-hcaptcha-response` attribute but don't know where to proceed from here to actually submit the solved hcaptcha and get a result.

```
await page.$eval('textarea[name="h-captcha-response"]', e => e.setAttribute("style", ""));

await page.$eval('textarea[name="h-captcha-response"]', e => e.setAttribute("data-hcaptcha-response", response));

await page.type('textarea[name="h-captcha-response"]', response);
```

this is my code for filling out the response I get from 2captcha service. I've read another article on how to get the callback in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68536051/how-to-find-hcaptcha-callback-function) and managed to get to this [image]
But honestly I have no idea how to use the data obtained to submit the hcaptcha token in terms of puppeteer / Node JS

The functions it returns have this in them, I think I should make use of the execute part but again, don't know how
[image]

Edit: this [link](https://releases.footshop.com/nike-x-undefeated-dunk-low-sp-dunk-vs-af1-GnAg73sB6RTO0K-RDoTJ) is where i'm looking to get the hcaptcha callback, the hcaptcha appears only once user fills out personal, delivery and shoe info.

Comment: That discord link is react. You would have to inspect the react properties to find the callback.